# In Route 53 can I add additiional CNAME records for one domain each going to different server

Tags: amazon-route53

If I have a domain name controlled by AWS Route53 can I have different CNAME records point to completely different servers (e.g two different EB services and a Cloudfront service and a Database)or do they all l have to go to different points on the same server

Comment: Yes it does indeed work, I assume there is no problem with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Route 53 resolves a domain name to an IP address ("A" Record), or redirects domain name resolution to a host name ("CNAME" record).

In both cases, the result will be an IP Address. DNS resolution does not involve port numbers, which are used to direct traffic after the IP address has been obtained.

So, yes, multiple domain names can point to the same "server" (effectively, the same IP address) and different domain names / CNAME records can point to the same server (IP address).